# flask: how to get a POST endpoint to redirect correctly

Tags: javascript, python, html, request, flask

Have a somewhat complicated endpoint in Flask that is currently deployed to a server:

```
@app.route('/whatever', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def somefunct:
    if request.method = 'POST':
        << do some stuff >>

    << do some other stuff >>
    return render_template('sometemplate.html', **<<variable dict>>)
```

that pushes to one template.

`sometemplate.html` is kind of tricky, it contains a table that pulls data from the variable dictionary and also provides a dropdown that allows the user to interact with it:

```
{% for item in << variable in dict >> %}

...

<td>
    <form name="category-form" id="category-form-{{ item }}" action="/whatever">
        <select name="{{ item }}" id="{{ item }}">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</td>
```

and then I have some javascript to trigger the right `POST` action (jQuery is loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for item in << variable in dict >> %}

    var form{{ item }} = $('category-form-{{ item }}');

    form{{ item }}.find('#{{ item }}').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form{{ item }}.attr('action'),
            data: form{{ item }}.serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log("calling {{item}}")
            }
        });
    });

    {% endfor %}
});
```

All of this works correctly in a dev environment, however when I push to our server, I'm getting `500` errors in the javascript console. My suspicion is that there's something funky going on with the `request` object -- I've been able to narrow down that I'm getting an error that I didn't get before when I try to parse through it.

As part of my troubleshooting, since I'm running an Apache server and don't have easy access to output, I was thinking that it might be wise to redo the endpoint as follows:

```
@app.route('/whatever', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    if request.method = 'POST':
        << do some stuff >>
        variable = << variable to test >>
        return render_template('test.html', **{"variable"=variable})

    << do some other stuff >>
    return render_template('sometemplate.html', **<<variable dict>>)
```

and set up test.html to just be:

```
{{ variable }}
```

(with correct blocks around it, etc.)

However, when I try to implement this, after selecting something from the dropdown, it doesn't redirect to `test.html`, though I can tell from the javascript console and creative use of the `return` statement in my code that it's tracing through the correct part of the endpoint.

My guess is that this is something to do with the way that my javascript is set up, but basically I want to be able to redirect to `test.html` in order to see what the request  object looks like and why it's malformed.

How do I do that redirect in this context?

Of course if you have any ideas about why this code wouldn't be working on the server when it's working on `localhost`, I'd be all ears as well :)

Comment: Can you run the application in debug mode on your server? That will show you a stack trace for the error.

Comment: sorry, this is probably really dumb, but how do I set that up?

Comment: Add `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` after you create the application instance.